# the way how Japanese is spoken?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-adverbs

In English, we have the expressions "the reason why" and "the place where," but is it correct to use "how" in the following?

> I can show them the way **how** Japanese is spoken.

Answer (score 2):

**It is not technically incorrect, but it is not the way English is usually spoken**

"the way" and "how" mean the same thing, so you are saying the thing twice.

Either of the following are preferred:

> I can show them the way Japanese is spoken.
>
> I can show them how Japanese is spoken.

There is [more discussion on the English language site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101086/is-the-way-how-wrong).

Comment: I agree, but in my view your explanation is an unhelpful rationalisation for what is an arbitrary fact about English. "The reason why" would also be ruled out by that argument (and my father used to rail against it), But it goes back to at least 1824 (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Song_of_the_Western_Men))

Comment: @ColinFine Your reasoning is backwards. The answer's explanation is perfectly rational - "the reason why" is the one that breaks convention.

Comment: @scatter: How about _the place where_? _the time when_? This sort of argument may be useful as a mnemonic, but it is mostly useless, because a) you can never tell which cases it applies to and which it doesn't, and b) there is no general linguistic prohibition on tautology anyway.

Comment: Why don’t you include: “the way **that** Japanese is spoken?”